# Workflow for "Through-Contact" Trajectory Optimization in Drake

Tags: drake

I would like ask what would be an appropriate workflow for solving a trajectory optimization problem that takes into account contact interactions between different bodies in an MBP in Drake. Problems like the ones addressed in this [paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0278364913506757?casa_token=iEATTk-LafUAAAAA:17aFFmpXiZ4qyXrgAeDvUfJK-VrHl6DmmMF3Kp50WRAe7QWQy67WA5EnnstnUvFNCh6qvkwByBmQ). I've tried using `DirectCollocation` class but apparently it does not consider contact forces as optimization variables. Is there anyway to incorporate them into the mathematical program generated by `DirectCollocation`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to consider when you plan through contact

1. The decision variables are not only the state/control any more, but should include the contact forces.
2. The constraints are not only the dynamic constraint x[n+1] = f(x[n], u[n]), but x[n+1] = f(x[n], u[n], λ[n]) where λ is the contact force, and also the complementarity constraint 0≤ λ ⊥ ϕ(q) ≥ 0
3. Instead of using direct collocation (which assumes the state trajectory being a piecewise cubic spline), Michael's paper uses just backward Euler integration, which assumes piecewise linear interpolation.

So you would need the following features:

1. Add the contact forces as decision variables.
2. Add the complementarity constraints.
3. Use backward Euler integration instead of `DirectCollocationConstraint`.

Unfortunately Drake doesn't have an implementation doing these yet. The closest match inside Drake is in this [folder](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/multibody/optimization), and the starting point could be the [StaticEquilibriumProblem](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/optimization/static_equilibrium_problem.h). This class does feature 1 and part of feature 2 (it has the complementarity constraint, but only static equilibrium constraint instead of dynamic constraint), but doesn't do feature 3 (the backward Euler step).

Comment: In pydrake, I can't seem to import some of the classes in the above folder. Such as `sliding_friction_complementarity_constraint`. They aren't listed in pydrake docs either. Is there a quick way I can import them to my Python program?

Comment: @Abdullab Nazir Sorry for the belated reply, I was on vacation. I can add the python binding of these classes. Could you give me a list of the classes/method that you want the python binding? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think `contact_wrench_evaluator` and `sliding_friction_complementarity_constraint` will be most useful for me. But, I'm worried that I've binary Drake installation. Will it be possible to update?